Can all congruences for a third-order recurrence relation hold for some composite $n$?
Let $p$ be a prime with $p \gt 3$. Consider the polynomial $f = x^3 - 3x -1$. Suppose $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Let $E$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, and let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the roots of $f$ in $E$. For $k \geq 0$, define $V(k) = \alpha^k + \beta^k + \gamma^k$. Using basic Galois theory, I can show that $$(1) V(p)=0,$$ $$(2) V(p+1) = -3,$$ $$(3) V(p+2) = +3 \text{ or } -6,$$ $$(4) V(p^2+1) = -3,$$ $$(5) V(p^2+2)=+3 \text{ or } -6$$. It is easy to show that $V(0)=3$, $V(1)=0$, $V(2)=6$ and that for $k>2$, $V(k)=3V(k-2)+V(k-3)$. According to a comment of Jyrki Lahtonen in this thread (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4995484/irreducibility-of-cubic-polynomials-over-finite-fields-f-p), $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ unless $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 9$.
This motivates the following question  in case $n>3$ is composite and $n \equiv \pm 2,\pm 4 \pmod 9$. Define $A(0)=1$, $A(1)=0$, $A(2)=2$ and for $k>2$ $A(k)=3A(k-2)+A(k-3)$. Can all of the congruences (1) $A(n) \equiv 0$ , (2) $A(n+1) \equiv -1$, (3) $A(n+2) \equiv +1 \text{ or } -2$,  (4) $A(n^2+1) \equiv -1$, (5) $A(n^2+2) \equiv +1 \text{ or } -2$ hold simultaneously, $\pmod n$ ?
I tried out the composites $n \equiv \pm2, \pm 4 \pmod 9$ for $3<n<1,000,000$. The high score is 2/5 congruences for $n=23,902$.
Among odd composite $n$ with $n \equiv \pm 2, \pm 4 \pmod 9$ and $1 \leq n<8,000,000$ I find 45 numbers that satisfy exactly one congruence from this paragraph. None satisfy two or more of the five congruences. For composite $n$ coprime to 30 with $n \equiv \pm 2, \pm 4 \pmod 9$ and $1 \leq n < 10^{10}$, I find 295 values of $n$ that satisfy exactly one of the five congruences above, and none satisfying two or more.

Have you tried this for small values of $n$?

I take it the congruences in the last paragraph are all modulo $n$?

Yes, the congruences in the last paragraph are all modulo $n$. I have not extensively tested just for this polynomial. However, $f=x^3-3x-1$ was the second polynomial to be tried in a probable prime test I ran based on third-order recurrence relations. No pseudoprimes were found for that test below $10^{12}$.

You are probably familiar with https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866094-6/S0025-5718-1987-0866094-6.pdf Adams, Characterizing Pseudoprimes for Third-Order Linear Recurrences, Mathematics Of Computation, Volume 48, Number 177, January 1987, Pages 1-15, and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerrinPseudoprime.html

Thanks, I'm somewhat familiar with the articles of Adams and Shanks on Perrin pseudoprimes.
